# Session attributes getting lost

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am having a problem with a relativly easy thing. I am trying to do a simple program, where you can log in and log out using the session.
The session is created, but I am always getting forwarded to panel servlet and then to NoCorrectSession page. As if on login page the server saw isActive attribute, and then on panel page had not.

```
//class Login extends HttpServlet
private RequestDispatcher pageLogin, pagePanel, pageError; //defined in init()

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String isBeingRequested = request.getParameter("isBeingRequested");
    if (session.getAttribute("isActive") != null) {
        //user has been logged in before, redirect him
        pagePanel.forward(request, response);
    } else if (isBeingRequested != null) {
        //user has entered data into the login page and submitted it            
        if (name.length() == 0) {
            //user has not stated his name
            pageError.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            //otherwise access is granted and account created 
            session.setAttribute("isActive", "yes");   //setting session to active
            pagePanel.forward(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        //neither of these? user just entered the login screen
        pageLogin.forward(request, response);
    }
}

//class Panel extends HttpServlet {
private RequestDispatcher pageNoCorrectSession;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //session has expired or never was started
    if (session.getAttribute("isActive") == null) {
        pageNoCorrectSession.forward(request, response);
    //session valid
    } else {
        //logged in - do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464453/using-sessions-in-java-servlet

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the project it turned out I've not made a mistake in these servlets, but in HTML code causing submitting a form directly to the panel servlet (and not creating the account object in the process). I know it is silly, but it was a great lesson. Expect the unexpected :P